# Subpixel rendering?

Tags: python, vb.net

Subpixel rendering is a way to increase the apparent resolution of a computer's liquid crystal display (LCD) or organic light-emitting diode (OLED) display by rendering pixels to take into account the screen type's physical properties. It takes advantage of the fact that each pixel on a colour LCD is actually composed of individual red, green, and blue or other color subpixels to anti-alias text with greater detail or to increase the resolution of all image types on layouts which are specifically designed to be compatible with subpixel rendering.

Comment: im not familiar with unity3d but you probably have to increase refresh rate by that i mean the Update method should be called more often.

Comment: is the framerate/refresh rate set above 30? Or 60 if you would like really smooth animations

Comment: and also, in the property inspector be sure to set your speed in script.

Comment: which version do you have?

Comment: in Edit -> Project Settings -> Quality, set VSync to Don't Sync. next script, set `Application.targetFrameRate = 60;` in any script's `Start()` void.

Comment: are you sure you have a decent pc to run that smoothly? i mean, it's strange, it should move smoothly with the default settings. I tested your code and it moves smoothly be the speed 0.01,0.1,1 or 10.

Comment: What is your framerate?

Comment: What are the numbers we are talking of? What are the x-y-z actualy values you are translating? May be `float`'s precision is not enough for very small amounts.

Comment: Maybe you see pixel aliasing, try with higher antialiasing value: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/QualitySettings-antiAliasing.html

Comment: @Anonymous I'll write one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you object is moving very slow compared to screen resolution you see pixel aliasing. As you can see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1fn0AjdTvqg) small changes in camera position result noticeable changes in rendering - see the fence.

You need to increase antialiasing in render settings. Try setting it to higher value [like here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/QualitySettings-antiAliasing.html)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start() {
        QualitySettings.antiAliasing = 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Name the `Update()` to `FixedUpdate()`.

[As Unity explains this in one of their tutorials](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/scripting/update-and-fixedupdate), the issue is `Update()` is called every frame and `FixedUpdate()` is called every physics step, which is a fixed time while frame time varies. Usually, non-physics object movement should be handled in `Update()` and physics based calculations and object manipulations -- moving the character in your case -- should be handled in `FixedUpdate()`.